# Laravel 5 | Many to Many Relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5

I'm new in laravel5.
I use "Many to Many" Relationships to get all messages based on the given tag.

MESSAGE MODEL :

```
   function tags(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\tags')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

TAGS MODEL :

```
  public function messages() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\messages', "messages_tags",     "messages_id", "tags_id");
  }
```

MY INPUT :

```
   $tag = App\tags::where('name','public')->first();
```

($tag :)

```
 App\tags {#681
 id: "5",
 name: "Public",
 created_at: "2016-02-10 13:51:36",
 updated_at: "2016-02-10 08:21:36",
 }
```

I tried to get Messages with Tag.

```
 $tag->messages()->get();
```

MY OUTPUT :

```
 []
```

But i have messages with the Tag "Public".

What is Wrong with my code ?

Comment: try to dd($tag->message)  then if you can see the result put $tag->message->get()

Comment: That also return "[]"

Comment: can you put your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Message` model in the `tags()` method you should provide the `messages_tags` pivot table name as well (including "messages_id" and "tags_id") and to access the `messages` you should use:

```
$tag->messages;
```

Or you may use (Eagre loading):

```
$tag = App\tags::with('messages')->where('name','public')->first();
```

Then use:

```
$tag->messages;
```

Comment: Thank Q Soo much... Its Working...!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Do you have any message related with given tag?

```
$tag = App\tags::where('name','public')->first();
dd($tag->messages()->get());
```

Comment: Please tag record and related message record, just dd selecting by id